# What are the differences between X DevAPI and Connectors & APIs?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I saw "X DevAPI" and "Connectors & APIs" from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html

What are the differences between X DevAPI and Connectors & APIs?

I am more familiar with PostgreSQL. If possible, which API does PostgreSQL have that is similar  to X DevAPI, or to Connectors & APIs?

Comment: https://insidemysql.com/tag/x-devapi/ . From a brief skim, seems to be an attempt to unify a relational-based and document-based interface in one API, using new features in MySQL 8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-introduction.html probably also worth a read. The older connector APIs just deal with relational data, I think. But that's just my skim-read opinion, you can easily research it further yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Is x devapi some standard (similar to JDBC)? Is it used by other RDBMS other than mysql?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I have literally only heard of it after I read this question, and my knowledge extends to skim-reading the two articles I linked you to. I'm sure you can use google just as adeptly as I can to find out more. Personally I would doubt it's any kind of standard or used anywhere else because, as I pointed out, it's trying to provide an interface to both a RDBMS style functionality with a document-database style functionality. Most RDBMSes don't offer that kind of document-database service, as far as I know. But it appears the newest MySQL does.

Answer (score 2):

The X DevAPI uses a new protocol based on Google Protobufs that provide features unable to be offered in the old protocol such as multiple non-blocking async queries, using MySQL as a NoSQL JSON Document Store with simple CRUD funtions. You can find the details at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-introduction.html